# C++ error in string replace

Tags: c++, string

I have created a function that replaces a string.

It looks like this:

```
void replace_with(wstring& src, const wstring& what, const wstring& with)
{    
    if (what != with) {
        wstring temp;
        wstring::size_type prev_pos = 0, pos = src.find(what, 0);
        while ( wstring::npos != pos ) {
            temp += wstring(src.begin() + prev_pos, src.begin() + pos) + with;
            prev_pos = pos + what.size();
            pos = src.find(what, prev_pos);
        }
        if ( !temp.empty() ) {
            src = temp + wstring(src.begin() + prev_pos, src.end());
            if (wstring::npos == with.find(what)) {
                replace_with(src, what, with);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, if my string is size==1, and the "what" is exactely the string, it will not replace it.

For example

```
wstring sThis=L"-";
replace_with(sThis,L"-",L"");
```

... will not replace the "-".

I don't see where I went wrong.

Can anybody help, please?

Comment: If this is purely a learning exercise, great, but otherwise, why aren't you using [`std::string::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main part of the function is working fine. The problem is the if (!temp.empty()) part, which makes absolutely no sense. Replace the entire if block with just the line

```
src = temp + wstring(src.begin() + prev_pos, src.end());
```

and it should work fine.

Hint: try to explain in words what the last part of the function is doing.

Answer (score 2):

```
void replace_with(wstring &src, wstring &what, wstring &with) {
    for (size_t index = 0; ( index = src.find(what, index) ) != wstring::npos ; ) {
        src.replace(index, what.length(), with);
        index += with.length();
    }       
}
```